# how to add a volume cube

Tags: mesh, interface, physics, geometry-nodes, volumetrics

I can't seem to add a volume cube in blender 3.2.2. I don't understand cause I am new but I saw a video called blender getting crazy at 0120 he added a volume cube in geometry nodes but that option doesn't even come up for me.

Comment: The *Volume Cube* node is a new node that comes with Blender 3.3 (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.3/Nodes_Physics - scroll down). Blender 3.3 is at the moment still a beta version. The official release is next month.

Comment: Damm, I am really amazed at how fast u answered me thank you. I tried searching everywhere.